# Modelling a second level table relationship

Tags: database-design, referential-integrity

I have three tables in my Database:

```
Customers 
---------- 
Id
Name

Addresses
----------
Id
Description
CustomerId

Orders
----------
Id
Description
CustomerId
DeliveryAddressId
```

I'd like to make sure that every Address referenced by DeliveryAddressId in the Orders table belongs to the Customer referenced by CustomerId.
How can I model this?

Answer (score 1):

I recently answered a question just like this one here:

[How to structure Tables with changing status without duplicating data](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/187173/how-to-structure-tables-with-changing-status-without-duplicating-data)

You have two options, create the foreign key from `Orders` using both the `AddressId` and `CustomerId` or remove the `CustomerId` entirely from the `Orders` table as you can obtain it through the relation anyway.